# Which one to use, into or onto?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct?

He's onto some other stuff
          or
He's into some other stuff.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to say, please specify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

He's "onto" - stresses the fact that he has "moved on"  (changed course...and is moving in a different direction).

He's "into" simply says that he is doing something different.

Comment: In the Sherlock Holmes example that Edwin gave, "onto" means following a new "lead".  This doesn't necessarily mean moving in "a different direction", as the lead could simply be confirming a suspicion.

Comment: I love Sherlock Holmes!  Of course the "context" is very important and if you are talking about "following a new lead" - then I would definitely suggest that you should use "onto".